# C# add items to a List <T> and display

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

Im trying to add different items to a List and then show in a Datagridview..

I have this but everytime I add a new item, replace the last item

```
 private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<alumno> p2 = new List<alumno>();
        p2.Add(new alumno() { telefono=(int.Parse(txtId.Text)), nombre=(txtNombre.Text), apellido=(txtApellido.Text) });
        dataGridView1.DataSource = p2;
    }
```

Comment: Every time you click on the button, you are creating a new, empty list, and adding one item to it. You probably want to store `p2` as an instance field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't persist your items anywhere.  You're just creating a new list every time:

```
List<alumno> p2 = new List<alumno>();
```

If your class itself is persistent, you can make it a class-level property:

```
private List<alumno> p2 = new List<alumno>();

private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    p2.Add(new alumno() { telefono=(int.Parse(txtId.Text)), nombre=(txtNombre.Text), apellido=(txtApellido.Text) });
    dataGridView1.DataSource = p2;
}
```

Note that in a web application this would be very different, because in web applications the class instance doesn't inherently persist.  In that case you'd want to persist the value somewhere else, and you have a number of options for that.  Page state, session state, application state, a database, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. in case I want to add more items to the list and keep the old ones.. ?

Comment: @luisk182: Well, that's the point of persisting the list somewhere outside of that one method.  So you can add more items to a single instance of the list instead of constantly creating a new instance.

Comment: I have already put the list outside of the method but, I can add only one item

Comment: @luisk182: If you've changed your code in some way, update the question with the new code.  If this is a web application, it would also be important to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the creation of the List out of the clickEvent. Because everytime you click the button a new List will be made and your previous List will be lost. You should first declare the List (for instance at the startup of your form) and then use the ClickEvent to add your item to the list

`List p2 = new List();

private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p2.Add(new alumno() { telefono=(int.Parse(txtId.Text)), nombre=(txtNombre.Text), apellido=(txtApellido.Text) });
        dataGridView1.DataSource = p2;
    }`